# How can I rename selected objects instead of just the active object?

Tags: python

I am trying to take all the selected objects and rename them based on their active material. I can make it work with the active object, but I can't figure out a way to do it with the selected objects.

This is what I have for the active object, that works as expected.

```py
import bpy

#takes active object and renames it to the active material
name = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name
bpy.context.object.name = name
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    if ob.select_get():
        #ob.name=ob.material_slots[0].name #this can fail if no material is assigned
        print(ob.name)
```

Or using context as @batFINGER suggests

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
     #ob.name=ob.material_slots[0].name #this can fail if no material is assigned
     print(ob.name)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a quick response and it works exactly as I hoped! Where is the best place to learn the for/if statements? and like, how do you know what "o" is?

Comment: bpy.data.objects is an iterable array, which means you can use a for statement to iterate over all of the values in the array. I called the variable "o", "ob" and "obj" are more common in example scripts, but its arbitrary. Each iteration of the for loop o points to one of the bpy.data.objects[] in the scene.

Comment: Suggest working from context and using `for o in context.selected_objects:`  is the current scene current selection.  As above will find all objects in blend file that are selected, whether in current scene, another scene or no scene.   @AlexPearce  the number of  teach yourself python links are too numerous.